Why doesn't chromedriver open the website?
I currently have a problem: I can't open the URL of any page in Chrome with simple code.
The Chrome window appears asking who was currently using Chrome and you can select the profiles there, but it quickly disappears and my program goes to error.
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from seleniumbase import Driver

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)

url = "https://www.google.de/"
driver.get(url)

Window like this:


You aren't using the just Chromedriver, you're using seleniumbase. Have you looked at their documentation to see what might be causing the issue? Have you tried just using Chromedriver? driver = webdriver.Chrome() using the latest Selenium version? You shouldn't have the same issue there.

Thank you. Yes, I have tried both variants and the same thing happens again and again. The Chrome window opens and quickly disappears without me being able to examine it and find the items to continue.

A simple form would be:
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#for deutsch in browser
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("lang=de")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.de/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()


Got this error and it doesnt work:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
(failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
(Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.86)
